# JBoss5 and JBoss7 installation conflict same Linux Machine

Tags: linux, bash, jboss, jboss7.x

I had a properly working JBoss7 installation, but recently on my machine my team mate installed JBoss5.1.0GA, Since then i am facing two problems and still unable to resolve them.

Whene ever i stop the jboss with init.d script. I get this error.

```
[root ~]# service jboss stop
Stopping jboss-as:                                         [  OK  ]
[root ~]# *** JBossAS process (25571) received KILL signal ***
grep: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid: No such file or directory
```

Could there be any conflict with the processID file that jboss generates to check weather server is running or not.
I doubt that there is a conflict with another JBoss5 Installation.

Second Issue is I am unable to connect with the server via jboss-cli.sh

```
[root bin]# sh jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect localhost
The controller is not available at localhost:9999
[disconnected /] connect localhost
```

One thing i want you to check, the **ps auxwww |grep jboss** commands result
I can see two process , is this any conflict ? With PId

```
root     25970  0.0  0.0 161476  1960 pts/0    S    07:58   0:00 su - jboss -c LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid /usr/share/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
jboss    25973  0.0  0.0 106096  1344 ?        Ss   07:58   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/share/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
jboss    26022  8.7  8.7 1027368 342776 ?      Sl   07:58   0:45 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/share/jboss-as/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/share/jboss-as/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/share/jboss-as -c standalone.xml
root     26365  0.0  0.0 103244   848 pts/0    S+   08:07   0:00 grep jboss
```

I can see multiple process started with command sh standalone.sh command.
Is this the interference ?

Comment: Are you sure that both instances use different ports?

Comment: on the jboss-cli issue, which ports do your server instances listen for the management interface?

Comment: @devnull Yes I have asked the other developer to set the port-offset to 100 i.e all ports of jboss5 will be incrimented by 100. And the other JBOss is Down totally now.

Comment: @eis Yes eis, My JBoss7 listens on port 9999 for native managment interface. Configured in standalone.xml

Comment: it doesn't seem so based on the jboss-cli error message. You could try to telnet to that port to see if there's anything listening.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no PID file, then you might have a permissions issue on /var/run/jboss-as

You should also check JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/console.log to see if there are any errors there

Answer (score 0):

Replying after a long time, but we were successfully able to run two instances of JBoss, with using `Port Binding Offset` and while connecting via Jboss-cli.sh provide your incremented Port.
If you set `port.binding.offset=2` then connect to port `10001` i.2 9999+2